# Why must a constructor's call to the superconstructor be the first call?

Tags: java, language-design, language-features, construction, constructors

It is an error if you do anything in a constructor before calling the superconstructor. I remember that I had problems because of that. Yet, I do not see how this saves us from errors. It could save you from using uninitialized fields. But, the Java compiler that checks for using uninitalized variables does that and this stupid rule does not improve anything here.

The only serious consideration argument I remember was that we need it for OOP, because objects in real life are constructed this way: you create a cucumber by first creating a vegetable and then add cucumber attributes. IMO, it is opposite. You first create a cucumber and, by [duck is a duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) principle, it becomes a vegetable. Another argument was that it improves safety. Not writing the code improves the dependability much better, so I do not consider this as argument. Creating more complex code when you need to workaround a stupid restriction, is what makes the program more error-prone.

This rule creates a serious pain (at least for me). So, I want to hear the serious argument and serious example where it could be useful.

Comment: Well,copy pasting your title into google turned up this as the first result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168345/why-does-this-and-super-have-to-be-the-first-statement-in-a-constructor

Comment: Don't assume that something you don't understand must be "stupid".

Comment: @jozefg's link to the Stack Overflow answer buttons this issue up nicely. Also, if calling the super constructor on an inherited object offends you so much try C#.

Comment: @Val As jozefg already linked an answer please read the answer first and don't flame around here (at Michael Borgwardt). There answer written on stack overflow is fine.

Comment: His link goes to the question. I do not understand which answer you are talking about!? Secondly, stop recommending another language. Start telling which language is better and why. This begs for answering if superconstructor must be the first. Recomming C# does not answer this question. It is a kind of diverting from the question.

Comment: @Val If you read the link you'll notice that the question has answers

Comment: @Val, I'm not sure if english is your first language, but you are coming across as very demanding and very rude.  This probably explains why, as you've mentioned, you've been banned from a forum for asking what you think is a reasonable question.  Step back and be a bit more careful with your words.   You can only expect constructive feedback if you yourself are being constructive.

Comment: @Tombatron, What do you mean by "try C#"?  The same thing is enforced in C#.  Before the subclass constructor is executed, unless specified otherwise, the default (parameterless) public or protected superconstructor is invoked.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MetaFight You are correct. However, it seems that Val's beef is that he must make an explicit call to super where C# will do implicitly (for parameter-less constructors).

Comment: You want a link directly to an answer? An answer that says WHY? OK: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6697760/203458

Answer (score 9):

The [object initialization sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) is complex enough as it is and already sometimes [causes headaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3404369/16883). Allowing subclasses to run code before the superclass constructor would make it more complex and confusing still, with more potential for subtle bugs, especially if there is a hierarchy of multiple classes which all do this.

It also reduces the conceptual coupling between superclasses and subclasses. You look at the superclass and can see how it will be initialized before it is used. Allowing subclass code to do arbitrary stuff before the superclass initialization could easily break some assumptions made by the superclass code, and subclasses should, as much as possible, not have to depend on understanding of implementation details of the superclass.

All in all, not allowing subclass code to run before the superclass is fully initialized leads to code that is easier to understand and less error-prone. It may sometimes require workarounds, but just because a rule prevents you from doing what would be convenient in your immediate circumstances does not mean it's a bad or stupid rule.

Comment: Huh? I regularly use code before the inherited call and have yet to run into problems with that. Even use it as a feature to initialize members exposed by the super class before being used in the super constructor so descendants get a handle on that without having to break out parts of the constructor into separate functions. Anyway, could it be that this argument is language specific? I use Delphi and all instance memory has been allocated and initialized before any of the constructors in the hierarchy run. Does that mean I am spoilt rotten? :-)

Comment: @MarjanVenema question is tagged Java, and init sequence is indeed important (and strictly specified) there. Eg invoking an abstract method (yet to be defined in subclass) in superclass constructor throws NPE - that's one of my favorite coding mistakes (luckily it's easy to discover, even in unit tests)

Comment: It was tagget 'Java' to discuss the restriction we see in that language, not to prohibit comparison with other OOP implementations.

Comment: @Gnat: thanks for the clarification. It helps me understand the question's significance.

Comment: @Marjan Venema: having a subclass manipulate superclass members which are then used in the superclass constructor is a *horrendously* bad practice. I'm pretty sure you've run into problems with that, although you may not have realized it's a consequence of doing so.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Nope, it isn't and I haven't. It actually is a very useful practice in standardizing construction/initialization code while allowing it to be influenced by the derived classes. I mostly use it in unit testing to give the interface contract test case the actual implementing class it should instantiate (the actual test case deriving from the contract test case) so I don't have to repeat all kinds of set up code in all concrete test classes - which is brittle and can lead to variance in testing that you don't want.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Also, it seems to me that whether it is a bad practice or not hugely depends on the language used and how it deals with construction and initialization of class members. Please don't judge practices in other languages based on your experience with a specific language (type) without extensive knowledge of that other language.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What makes deferred super initialization acceptable in Delphi that breaks in Java? If you've realized something important, it might be a good answer.

Comment: @Marjan Venema: yes it is, and you may not have had problems because you use it on code maintained only by a single person. And I really don't see how the badness of the practice is in any way language specific. It's conceptually bad, not technically. Of course, there's always cases where there are no better alternatives. I'll readily admit that I cannot judge where your example is such a case.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I'd rather avoid using words like _horrendous_, as these shift things into better-worse holy wars territory. It's unlikely that design choices are based on a reasoning like that, especially in scrupulously designed and specified language like Java. I'd rather bet there was sort of _impartial evaluation_ involved here, like comparing and weighting benefits and drawbacks of various available options. Like _flexibility vs simplicity_, stuff like that...

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt: Why do you presume I work on code maintained by only one person? If you can't see how differences between languages and even compilers can cause different things to be bad or not, then there is nothing to discuss. It is your opinion that it is conceptually bad, I beg to differ and submit that this opinion is based on years of <strike>indoctrination</strike>experience in a specific (set of) languages and compilers.

Answer (score 4):

When you inherit from an object, you may not be able to see the implementation of the constructor or underlying methods.

*There may be more going on in the constructor than just initialization of variables.*
such as hardware access, database access, network communication, etc. Not saying this is good design or not - just saying you may not be aware of it.

But even if it *was* just variables. There may be member functions that rely on those variables being instantiated properly. There may be function calls that occur in the instantiation of those variables. Because of encapsulation you can't be sure that isn't the case, so to be safe you fully construct your base item first - otherwise your implementation may cause the super class to "break".

And it works the other way around to. If someone inherits from your class, you know that your construction code will execute properly. **The programmer inheriting your class can never break your code, just his.** If he is having a problem, he knows he should check his code.

Comment: Ok, you say "do not call inherited methods before super is initialized". But, requirement for super() be the first is different. It says that I cannot initialize my own, newly introduced fields before calling the super(). Do you feel the difference? Secondly, your database may fail if the order of method calls is wrong. Preinitializing the parent object does not save from that. Right? The super object designer must specify the proper order of calls, including super(). That is why I say that super-first does not add anything. I do not see how your answer addresses these issues.

Comment: By forcing the super() call first it assures that the base object is fully constructed. The goal here is to make sure nothing you do will break the super class's code. At least, that is the reason for it.

Technically, even if the code you introduce works - but it causes the super class's code to not work the way it was intended - you broke it. And it doesn't matter if it does break it - it matters if it COULD break it.

Comment: Do I break the supreclass if call first method_B then method_A whereas it required method_A then method_B? **Could** I brake it?

Comment: @Val: If the superconstructor calls `method_A` which initializes a resource that `method_B` requires, *but* in your subclass constructor you call `method_b` *before* `super()`, then `method_b` might be expecting the resource to be ready to use, but it isn't and that could cause runtime errors.

Comment: I say nothing about super(). I start with case where method A and B are called on initialized object. The workflow demands A first. You mistakenly call B first and break something in the object. Will this break the object? Could wrong order of calls break an initialized objects? Object constantly evolves. How can you say that it is completely initialized? Could wrong order of method invocations break the initialized object?

Comment: Yes, it could in this case break the object. If there are methods inside the base object that require a variable to be set to a valid value, the original class author will make sure it's set in the class construction method. By doing anything in an inherited class's constructor before the super class is allowed to initialize, you could potentially call a method before those values were set. The exception would be thrown by the super class, even though the inherited class was responsible... or even worse, an exception wouldn't be thrown. Either way, you may not be able to see why.

Answer (score 3):

> You first create a cucumber and, by duck is a duck principle, it becomes a vegetable.

Except Java isn't a structurally (duck) typed language. It's a nominatively typed language.

**If** Java was a structurally typed language (or simply a dynamic one), then your mental picture of how it works would be good.

Since it is not, it needs to build the object layout in memory which is most efficiently done by layering the derived types around the base types (think Shrek's onion) so that the base type's layout can be reused for just the base type as well as its derived types.

Does it have to be that way? Not at all, and it often isn't for languages that are not nominatively typed (or can have multiple base types). But in Java it is, and frankly is one of the least onerous restrictions the language puts on you.

As for your question, you're getting pushback because you come off as a know-it-all who clearly does not. It's good to ask why, but to say that this design is completely stupid because it's causing you trouble (because you can't do object oriented design well) is ignorant at best.

And yes, if you're in a scenario where you *want* to do operations in the constructor before calling the base constructor that is a pretty solid indication that you're not so great at OOD.

Comment: Indeed, I ask this question because I am not great at OOD. But, those who defend the superconstructor produce logic like this, http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/206657/63834 They say that vegetable must be built before cucumber because cucumber IS A vegetable and, similarly, 2nd floor is related with the 1st one! This nonsense makes me to think that learning perfect OO design destroys people minds. How do you prove that student's feeling that lang is wrong means that student is stupid? How do you prove that lang is wrong? By praising it first?

Comment: @val - In general, the language is never wrong. It might do it _weirdly_, but there are many, many ways to model computation.

Comment: If language is never wrong then having superconstructor first is as good/bad as not doing it?

Comment: @val - eh? Requiring the superconstructor first is a design choice. Many languages don't require it. Some do though, and do so for good reasons. It just happens that two of the most popular languages (Java, C#) have that constraint.

Answer (score 1):

**In layman's words:**

An inheritance relationship is an **"IS A"** relationship.

If `Human` inherits from `Ape`, it means that a `Human` is, firstly, an `Ape` then a `Human`. ( I'm not saying humans descent from apes, but that they are apes ).

It makes sense that you first initialize your `Ape` self in order to built upon it and get to be your `Human` self.

The superclass is the base you built upon, meaning you have to have an instance of the supeclass to extend from.

It makes no sense to built the second story of your house prior to building the first story.

Comment: @Val [Calm down and **be nice**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Comment: You cannot create an instance of fruit before apple. You first create apple and it happens to be a fruit. In reality fruit does not exist alone, without apple. Changing fruits -> apes does not change this. Even the magic spelling **IS A** will not do it for you. Secondly, store2 **IS NOT A** store1. So, your theory of construction seems natural for an OOD practitioner, but is incompatible with reality. The fact that you have to use wrong analogy to support it just proves that.

Comment: @Val: your previous comment was deleted because, while you were trying to point out problems with the answer in a reasonable fashion, you got kinda personal. I've corrected your last comment - please try to stick to critiques of the *answer itself*, not its author.